# How can I preserver &quot; when loading XML doc with C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

### I am trying to open an XML file, edit some of the nodes and save it again.

The XML document has double quotes escaped (`"`) and when I open it, it will decode all escaped characters and when is save it back it wont escape double quotes `"`.

How can i make sure that `"` are saved as `&quot;`?

The code that I am using to do this:

```
XmlDocument xliffDoc = new XmlDocument();
xliffDoc.Load(filePath);

XmlNamespaceManager xmlNSS = new XmlNamespaceManager(xliffDoc.NameTable);
xmlNSS.AddNamespace("st-xmlns", @"urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2");

foreach (XmlNode transUnit in transUnits)
{
  //Change innerXML while keeping the structure
}
xliffDoc.Save(filePath);
```

I expect that unchanged content to be saved as is:

```
.....
<trans-unit id="17645" identifier="5df0c6519f50ac44d2e9c94c1cf841d4" approved="yes">
  <source>LDL (&quot;Bad&quot; Cholesterol)</source>
  <target>LDL („Schlechtes“ Cholesterin)</target>
  <note>Context: me.body.ldl.text</note>
</trans-unit>
.....
```

but instead I get

```
.....
<trans-unit id="17645" identifier="5df0c6519f50ac44d2e9c94c1cf841d4" approved="yes">
  <source>LDL ("Bad" Cholesterol)</source>
  <target>LDL („Schlechtes“ Cholesterin)</target>
  <note>Context: me.body.ldl.text</note>
</trans-unit>
.....
```

Comment: Why is it a problem? The elements in the XML document have the same content (when parsed).

Comment: No,original content is `LDL (&quot;Bad&quot; Cholesterol)` and when i save is saved as `LDL ("Bad" Cholesterol)`

Comment: For XML it's the same content, so why is it a problem?

Comment: Because the tool that is going to use this XML, will use the text on HTML page

Comment: What tool are you using to read the XML file and place the text on the HTML page? You can have `"` on a HTML page without replacing it with `&quot;`, unless you use it inside an attribute. Maybe the problem should be fixed in the tool you are using because the XML document looks fine as it is (with the `"` instead of `&quot;`. This sounds like an XY problem. Do you have a link or description of the tool you are using?

Comment: @Mamphir did you resolve this?